# How do I find the equivalence class of 0? I already wrote the proof.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-writing, relations, equivalence-relations

What is the equivalence class of 0?

Comment: You haven't proved that your relation is symmetric. On the other hand, a~0 iff $2\mid a+0$. Can you conclude from that?

Comment: Let $a\in\mathbb{Z}$. Clearly, $2|a+a$. Thus, $a\sim a$. Hence, reflexive property holds.

Comment: @ash Please do not deface your question, in courtesy to those who already commented or answered, and also to others who may find it useful in the future.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

This relation is nothing else than `a and b have the same parity`.

Answer (score 0):

The equivalence class of $0$ is given by
\begin{align}
[0]&=\{a\in\mathbb{Z}:a\sim 0\}\\
&=\{a\in\mathbb{Z}:2|a\}\\
&=\{\dots, -4, -2, 0, 2, 4, \dots\}
\end{align}